# view thumbnail link putting a 0 after my url when clicked - why?

Tags: views, 6

I created this view with a thumbnail containing a link that leads to the full node. The URL to the full node is the name of the node with a 0 after it. For example instead of localhost/sitename/name-of-the-node the URL becomes localhost/sitename/name-of-the-node-0.

What shows up then is a sort of 'stripped' version of the full node where in my case the node title is missing, the full body text will show up but its hard to style with css and things are weird.

The node type I made the view for is 'evenement' (dutch for event) where I only added a field to fill in event date and a picture upload on top of the basic fields. 
In the view which I called 'calendar' under default the following settings

**DEFAULT**

Basic settings:

- Row Style: fields

Fields:

- Content: Date (standard)
- Node: title
- Node: body
- Content: image (thumbnail image)
   Then, I checkboxed "Link this field to its node"
- Node: AddThis button

No Sort Criteria

Filters:

- Node: Published (Yes)
- Node: Type = Evenement
- Content: Date (contains 2011)

**PAGE**

Page settings:

- Path: Calendar
- Menu: no menu

Comment: Provide details about your view config, maybe some screenshoots

Comment: Person I'm making site for doesn't appreciate stuff floating around like screeshots otherwise I would have. Hopefully the info I added is of help though. thanks for quick response

Comment: If you go to Content management -> Content -> List have you also the -0 at the end of your node ?

Comment: I can't believe I didn't check that first. From there the answer came. It showed the same node was already created at an earlier point and pathauto automatically put a zero after the pathname the second time the node with the same title got entered.